# How to replace . with space in Vim

Tags: vim

I copied the following to vim. Now I want to delete all . dots/periods. I tried `:%s/./ /g` But it does not give me the desired result.

How can delete them at once?

Thank you in advance.

```
a. Percent.................................................................................................
I4-15
b. Percent and Fractions ..........................................................................16-19
c. Percent and Decimals ...............................................................................20
d. EstimatingPercents..................................................................................21
13
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The command is correct, but you need to add a `\` in front of the period – `:%s/\./ /g` – since regular expressions use `.` as an "any character" wildcard.

Comment: If I read that correctly, then your replacement is a space.  You can use `:%s/\.//g` if you want to delete the `.` characters instead of replacing them with spaces.